# Session invalidation in FF , Tomcat

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat6

I am using Tomcat web container. I have an admin console app implemented. When I click on logout a session attribute is made null and invalidated see the below code in my logout.jsp file.
After logout the user is taken to the login page. In fireFox I click back button I have the below issues.
First I do not get page expired page like in IE 
Second when I click on any of the link in the page , I check for the sessioon attribute which I made null in logout. The value of that is "success". 
I am totally confused with this behaviour. Is it issue with firefox or tomcat session management.

I am sure I need more knowledge to understand this behaviour. Appreciate your help in letting me know what happens here...

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%
response.setHeader("cache-control","no-cache");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires",-1);

%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <% 
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    System.out.println("session"+session);
    session.setAttribute("loginStatus",null);
    session.invalidate();
  %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The headers are incomplete. You need the following set of headers:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

Escpecially the `must-revalidate` entry fixes this particular FF issue.

#### See also

- [Making sure a webpage is not cached across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)
- [Caching tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)

---

Unrelated to the actual problem, I've a few comments about this piece of code:

- You should prefer UTF-8 over ISO-8859-1 to gain [world domination](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html).
- Raw Java code in a JSP page is [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). The response headers needs to be set in a `Filter` and the logout needs to happen (indirectly) in a `Servlet`.
- Calling `getSession(false)` with `false` may return a `null` session which in turn can lead to a `NullPointerException` in certain circumstances. Get rid of `false` or at least add a nullcheck.
- Setting attribute to `null` right before calling `invalidate()` is unnecessary. The `invalidate()` call already trashes all the attribtues.

Hope you learn something from this.

Comment: Hi BalusC, Thank you for sharing your expertise and kind advise. I am thank ful to you.